# How to leave Ranorex' command prompt open after test suite has finished?

Tags: ranorex

By default, the command prompt closed. I cannot find an option to leave it open once the test suite finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a workaround.

1. Go to your xxxx.rxtst foler
2. Add a user code module as the last step to your test
3. In this newly added code module, add a line, `Console.Read()`, which will force this command window to stay open indefinitely. Please remember it is a workaround and please take this out of your production code.

Comment: Thanks very much. Since it is not designed for production, my ideal solution would be to have a Ranorex Studio specific setting, which also does not get commited into the version control system and, hence, does not make it into production.